# Samsung Galaxy J3 2017 SM-J330FN nandroid backup

Tags: backup, nandroid

I installed: Samsung_USB_Driver_v1.7.23.0, opened: odin3_v3.14.4 and started Odin 3. In AP I uploaded the file: twrp3.1.1-1_J330. I booted my Samsung Galaxy J3 2017 SM-J330FN in download mode; I connected it to the PC via the data cable and clicked START in Odin 3. The smartphone restarted in mode: TWRP. I tried to backup the system to SD card with TWRP, but every now and then it gave me errors and in the end it appeared: Backup Failed. Where is the mistake? Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: you should read recovery.log for reason